# Inotify: monitoring only some files inside a folder

Tags: c, linux, inotify

I'm writing a simple thread in C to monitor the modification to files inside a directory. There are several files inside the directory and some of them change frequently. I want to monitor few specific files.

I read carefully the Linux manual but I didn't find the answer
Thanks
Regards
Patrizia

Answer (score 0):

You can't exclude files, but you could only subscribe to create/delete events for the folder and add more fine-grained watches (i.e. also modifications) for individual files via `inotify_add_watch`.